Spring JPA - Can we override the native SQL for save method of JPA repository in Update case
I am using Spring boot and JPA repository for my application For database i am using PostgreSQL database.
I have crores of data in my table employee.
Due to performance issue i have implemented database partition on employee table with partition column of company_id.
so whenever i perform any database query on employee table i always pass the company_id condition for the batter performance.
now the question is that when i perform any changes in employee record i always use Save method of JPA repository. The save method internally create the native SQL query for update the record but it update the row by only emp_id (PK). Due to this the performance again goes down because we do not have company_id check in where condition.
Now i want to add Company_id check in entity update operation for the batter performance how should i achieve this.
Please let me know if any additional information is required.
Please guide. Thanks

Check the concept of composite primary key. In your case composed of emp_id and company_id. Using it will improve performance not only of save method but all other CRUD methods currently operating on emp_id.

@Mar-Z I have idea about it.. It automatically creates the query with company_id in where clouse ?

Sure. The composite key will be used by JPA (and Hibernate) instead of Long type I'd.

partitions in DB do not improve OLTP performance

@Mar-Z in my existing system i already have one primary key how can i create composite key? can you please guide me..

What about this solution?
You can create a custom method in your JPA repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    // Custom method to update an employee by company_id and emp_id
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Employee e SET e.salary = :newSalary WHERE e.companyId = :companyId AND e.empId = :empId")
    void updateEmployeeSalary(@Param("companyId") Long companyId, @Param("empId") Long empId, @Param("newSalary") BigDecimal newSalary);
}

